# I create my own library in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting the Unable to load the requested class: url

my library code is :-Curl_lib.php

```
<?php
class Curl_lib
{
    function hello()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('url');
        $msg = "Hello";  
        return $msg;
    }
}
?>
```

Controller code is:

```
<?php
class Curl extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('curl_lib');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    function get_content()
    {  
        $message = $this->curl_lib->hello();
        echo $message;    
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it

`Url` is not Library. it is **Helper class**.

```
<?php
class Curl_lib
{
    function hello()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('url');
        $msg = "Hello";  
        return $msg;
    }
}
?>
```